# How to use ng-repeat in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with this ng-repeat?  Nothing is displaying in the table that uses ng-repeat.

html:

```
<div  ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="conn1">
    <button ng-click="fetch()">fetch</button><br/>
    user name: {{user.name}}<br/>
    <p>
    <table>
        <tr><td>name</td></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="auser in everyuser">
        <td>{{auser.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

var conn1 = myApp.controller("conn1", function($scope, $http){

    var onFetchDone = function(response){
    $scope.user = response.data;
    $http.get($scope.user.repos_url)
        .then(onGetAllDone);
  };

  $scope.onGetAllDone = function(response){
    $scope.everyuser = response.data;
  };

  $scope.fetch = function(response) {
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/gabrielecirulli")
        .then(onFetchDone);
  };

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/stq62jxL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions `onGetAllDone`   is set as property of scope object, promise chaining will not evaluate the function reference automatically from the scope.

Instead just define it as:

```
  function onGetAllDone(response){
    $scope.everyuser = response.data;
  };
```

Or set it as:

```
  .then($scope.onGetAllDone)
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dmtt0y5b/)**

Comment: Thanks!  As a side note, do you know any other sites that will return data this way...that I can use as another test?

Answer (score 1):

`onGetAllDone` is define on scope object. Hence you need to prefix it with `$scope`

`$http.get($scope.user.repos_url).then($scope.onGetAllDone);`